# convert object array to react component

Tags: reactjs

We have object array like below,

```
const obj = {
  1: [{
    row: 1,
    name: 'file1'
  }, {
    row: 1,
    name: 'file2'
  }],
  2: [{
    row: 2,
    name: 'file3'
  }]
}
```

Based on that above element I want to generate react component like below

```
  <React.Fragment>
    <h2>Elment: 1</h2>
     <div>file1</div>
     <div>fiel2</div>
    <h2>Element: 2</h2>
     <div>file3</div>
   </React.Fragment>
```

I want to see how we can fit `React.Fragments` for this sample object.

### Update

Just to clarify `Element: {key}`, where the `key` is taken from object key.

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const obj = {
  1: [{ row: 1, name: "file1" }, { row: 1, name: "file2" }],
  2: [{ row: 2, name: "file3" }]
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = Object.keys(obj).map(key =>
      obj[key].map((item, index) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          {index < 1 && <h1> Element {key} </h1>} {}
          <strong> File: </strong> {item.name}{" "}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <p>IM THE APP</p>
        {data}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image: Edit xovjn02xrw]

This is how you would do it, all thats left for you to do is organize, order, and style it inside of the `map`.

In depth:

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

```
 const data = Object.keys(obj).map(key =>
  obj[key].map((item, index) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      {index < 1 && <h1> Element {key} </h1>} {}
      <strong> File: </strong> {item.name}{" "}
    </React.Fragment>
  ))
);
```

Once we do `Object.keys(obj)` we map through the keys with `Object.keys(obj).map` and use that to access one array of objects at a time inside of the original object. Inside of our other map function we map that current array and return our `jsx`.

Comment: thanks for solution. But the `Element#1` should be repeated once  and is it possible to use Fragment?

Comment: still need help? im here and ready if you need it let me know

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to code and maintain, if you flatten your input object.

may be convert the existing

```js
const obj = {
  1: [{
    row: 1,
    name: 'file1'
  }, {
    row: 1,
    name: 'file2'
  }],
  2: [{
    row: 2,
    name: 'file3'
  }]
}
```

```js
const obj = [{
  row: 1,
  names: ['file1', 'file2']
}, {
  row: 2,
  names: ['file3']
}]
```

Once the conversion is done, it would be a very simple iteration using maps and Components.

A detailed solution with code is here at [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bu7419)

Working solution [Output](https://react-bu7419.stackblitz.io)